# Nginx Default index page redirection

Tags: nginx

Based on some condition, for instance, based on User-Agent, I would like to determine the default index page. Inside IF condition, I couldn't be able to use the index keyword. What should I do to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

UPDATES

I was able to resolve this, with default index as `index.htm`

and a rule

```
location /index.htm {
   if ($SOME_CONDITION = true) {
      rewrite ^ /mindex.htm;
   }
}
```

I don't know, whether this is the right approach. Please add up if this problem has better solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (googlebot|bingbot)) {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html last;
 }
```